# Error on Upsert in Prisma+TypeScript with n-to-m relationship

Tags: typescript, prisma, upsert

I have a n-to-m relationship between GroceryItems and Nutrients with following Prisma schema in my TypeScript+TsEd.io+Koa+Prisma backend stack:

```
model GroceryItem {
  /// @TsED.Groups("!creation")
  id         String    @id @default(cuid())
  name       String    @unique
  nutrients  GroceryNutrient[]
}

model GroceryNutrient {
  itemId     String
  nutrientId String
  item       GroceryItem @relation(fields: [itemId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  nutrient   Nutrient    @relation(fields: [nutrientId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  amount     Float
  unit       String

  @@id([itemId, nutrientId])
}

model Nutrient {
  /// @TsED.Groups("!creation")
  id         String    @id @default(cuid())
  name       String    @unique
  itemNutrients GroceryNutrient[]
}
```

Assuming that the database contains the following data:

```
groceryItems: [
  { id: "xyz", name: "Banana" }
]

nutrients: [
  { id: "123", name: "Magnesium" },
  { id: "124", name: "Potassium" },
  { id: "125", name: "Natrium" },
]

groceryNutrients: [
  { itemId: "xyz", nutrientId: "123", amount: 1, unit: "g" },
  { itemId: "xyz", nutrientId: "124", amount: 2, unit: "mg" },
]
```

From the frontend I do receive the `id` and the grocery `item` data as REST parameter and body, respectivelly. For example:

```js
const id = "xyz";
const item = {
  id: "xyz",
  name: "Banana",
  nutrients: [
    { id: "123", name: "Magnesium", amount: 100, unit: "g" },
    { id: "125", name: "Natrium", amount: 200, unit: "g" }
  ]
};
```

I want to use an upsert in order to update the nutrient `123`, delete the nutrient `124` and add the new nutrient `125` to the item `Banana`. My code so far throws a `PrismaClientValidationError on update()`.

```js
  async updateItem(
    @Required() @PathParams("id") id: string,
    @Required() @BodyParams() item: GroceryItem
  ) {
    return prisma.groceries.update({
      where: { id: id },
      data: {
        name: item.name,
        nutrients: {
          upsert: item.nutrients.map(nutrient => ({
            where: {
              itemId_nutrientId: {
                itemId: id,
                nutrientId: nutrient.id
              }
            },
            update: {
              amount: nutrient.amount,
              unit: nutrient.unit,
              item: { connect: { id: id } },
              nutrient: { connect: { id: nutrient.id } }
            },
            create: {
              amount: nutrient.amount,
              unit: nutrient.unit,
              item: { connect: { id: id } },
              nutrient: { connect: { id: nutrient.id } }
            }
          }))
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

Until now I have focused solemnly on inserting and updating connections between the grocery items and nutrients, not removing them. I have not found a solution online from: StackOverflow, the official Prisma documentation and ChatGPT4.

PS: can I incorporate a delete logic for the nutrient `124` in this code? I would like to keep the update atomic through a single database call to prevent inconsistencies.